# trying to change 24hr to 12hr format

Tags: javascript, time-format

I've looked up different options to change the format but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right since none work.

```
let hrs = document.getElementById(hours)
let min = document.getElementById(minute)
let sec = document.getElementById(second)


setInterval(()=>{
    
  let currenTime = new Date();
  

hours.innerHTML = (currenTime.getHours()<10?"0":"") + currenTime.getHours();

minute.innerHTML = (currenTime.getMinutes()<10?"0":"") + currenTime.
getMinutes();

second.innerHTML = (currenTime.getSeconds()<10?"0":"")+ currenTime.
getSeconds();
},1000)
```

```
if(hours == 0){
hours = 12;
}
```

Comment: Why not do `toTimeString` and tweak the hours part?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `hour12` option of the [`toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method.

```js
const d = new Date()
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, { hour12: true }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let hrs = document.getElementById(hours)
let min = document.getElementById(minute)
let sec = document.getElementById(second)


setInterval(()=>{
    
  let currenTime = new Date();
  let Hours= currenTime.getHours()
  if(Hours>12){
    Hours=Hours-12
   }
   if(Hours<10){
   Hours="0"+Hours
   }
hours.innerHTML = Hours;

minute.innerHTML = (currenTime.getMinutes()<10?"0":"") + currenTime.
getMinutes();

second.innerHTML = (currenTime.getSeconds()<10?"0":"")+ currenTime.
getSeconds();
},1000)
 
if(hours == 0){
hours = 12;
}
```

Comment: damn awesome ty